# Without using sharing rules how can i share records to another user?

Tags: sharing, configuration, sharing-rule

Without using   sharing rules   how can i   share   records to  another user?

Comment: Why can't you use sharing rules? What are you trying to do, specifically?

Answer (score 2):

For automated sharing, where possible it is far easier to use Sharing Rules than other forms of sharing. If you really cannot use Sharing Rules, there are options such as Apex Sharing, though these require explicit coding to support them and, if you want to make it possible to support this approach regardless of the Org Wide Defaults for sharing, you have to be careful to use entirely dynamic DML when creating or deleting the sharing records since the sharing record objects only "appear" in your org when OWDs are not Public Read/Write.

Of course, if you are not automating this, your users can now use manual sharing even in Lightning Experience.

See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm) for more details on the various forms of sharing.

Comment: Thanku...By using Apex Sharing I have done this..